# Ubuntu 12.04 Android SDK Manager only show the installed packages

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and I downloaded  adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702.zip from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.
When open "Android SDK Manager" to install the packages, i got the error as: "failed to fetch url https //dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml reason file not found".
In "Android SDK Manager", there're only the installed packages list but not the uninstalled ones. Now i would like to install Android 4.4.2(API 19) however there's no way to do it.
And why this error happens: "failed to fetch url https //dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml reason file not found"? Does anybody know why the uninstalled packages not showing in "Android SDK Manager"?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of adt-bundle and then try to install google api from sdk manager. I was also face the same issue and this thing is work for me. Thanks